# Error: Unknown property 'LeadConvert.VF_Lead__c

Tags: visualforce

Visualforce Error:

### Error: Unknown property 'LeadConvert.VF_Lead__c

Comment: Could you add your VF and controller code ? Your page is looking for a LeadConvert variable in your controller or a  VF variable for your datatable/repeater/..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because:

- You have not defined any property named `LeadConvert` in Controller Apex class.
- If you have defined, it is not `public` or if it is public, you have not defined `{get; set;}` for it. It should look like `public anyLeadCollectionObject leadConvert {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1):

Is `LeadConvert` an sObject (possibly you have `public Lead leadConvert;` somewhere in your controller / extension?

If that's the case - check regal's answer regarding getter (setter is not necessarily needed, depending how it's used on your Visualforce page).

But also verify that the `VF_Lead__c` really is present on the object and that it's at least visible in terms of field level security.